# Pagination not displaying proper results on second page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pagination

I've been trying to make this work for some time now. I have a `<select` tag for displaying number of results on a page. Apparently, the query works on displaying all rows, but when I go to the second page, it doesn't work anymore. I've checked out a thread about using `$_REQUEST` variable but to no avail.

**FORM**

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="adNum" name="showAdsOptions" aria-describedby="categoryHelp"> 
                    <option value="10">Show 10 ads per page</option>
                    <option value="15">Show 15 ads per page</option>
                    <option value="20">Show 20 ads per page</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" name="filterAds" class="form-control" value="Go" />
            </div>
</form>
```

**TABLE**

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <?php

        include 'admin/script/connection.php';
        $limit = 5;
        $counter = 1;
        $me = $_SESSION['user'];

        $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM user_pending_ads WHERE User_Name='$me'";
        $result = $conn->query($selectSQL);
        $total = $result->num_rows;

        if (isset($_GET['p']) == null) {
            $p = 0;
        } else {
            $p = $_GET['p'];
            if($p == 1) {
                $p = $p-1;
            } else {
                $p = ($p-1) * $limit;
            }
        }

        if ($limit > $total) {
            $nop = 1;
        } else {
            $nop = $total/$limit;
        }
        $nop = ceil($nop);
        $display = "SELECT * FROM user_pending_ads WHERE User_Name='$me' LIMIT $p, $limit";

        // SEARCH QUERY
        if (isset($_GET['searchAds'])) {
            if (isset($_GET['q']) == null) {
                $display = "SELECT * FROM user_pending_ads WHERE User_Name='$me' LIMIT $p, $limit";
            } else {
                $search = $_GET['q'];
                if ($search == "") {
                    $display = "SELECT * FROM user_pending_ads WHERE User_Name='$me' LIMIT $p, $limit";
                } else {
                    $display = "SELECT * FROM user_pending_ads WHERE User_Name='$me' AND Ad_Title LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $p, $limit";
                }
            }
        }

        // IF SHOW # ADS PER PAGE IS SET AND GO IS CLICKED
        if (isset($_POST['filterAds']) == true) {
            $opt = $_REQUEST['showAdsOptions'];
            $display = "SELECT * FROM user_pending_ads WHERE User_Name='$me' LIMIT $p, $opt";
        }

        $getdisplay = $conn->query($display);
        while ($col = $getdisplay->fetch_assoc()) {
            ...
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```

**PAGINATION**

```
<ul class="pagination">
            <?php
            if ($total >= 1) {
                ?>
                <li><a href="?p=1" class="btn btn-info">First</a></li>
                <?php
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $nop; $i++) {
                ?>
                    <li><a href="?p=<?php echo $i ?>" class="btn btn-info"><?php echo $i ?></a></li>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            <li><a href="?p=<?php echo $nop ?>" class="btn btn-info">Last</a></li>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't see where `$me` is defined.

Comment: My bad. It's a `$_SESSION` variable for the user logged in.

Comment: make sure the session array does have value and `if (isset($_POST['filterAds']) == true)` which is wrong for a few reasons; you need to separate those in 2 conditions or removing one, being `if (isset($_POST['filterAds']))`. Use error reporting.

Comment: What do you mean with " it doesn't work anymore" ? It shows no results, produces a PHP error shows wrong results....?

Comment: @Fred-ii- it does have value, the `select` tag is the problematic part. @Oscar, it shows results but it shows ALL the results when I navigate from page 2, basically it just works on the first page when `$_GET['filterAds']` is set

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['q']) == null)` all of those also, are all wrong and I don't know what you want to use here. What that translates to is this: "if is set equals null". As you can see, my sentence for it doesn't make sense, right? If you're wanting to check if the GET array is set, then don't use the `==null`. if you're wanting to check if it's equal to nothing or null, then don't use `isset`. Those and the other one I talked about, will always evaluate to being true.

Comment: Could you `echo $display;` before executing the query?

Comment: @Fred-ii- that part is not the problem. it's the pagination from page 2 that I'm having a problem at. That part works fine. That statement is only for putting a blank input on my search box, and it's not the help that I'm asking for.

Comment: @OscarPérez here is the result: `SELECT * FROM user_pending_ads WHERE User_Name='staff1' LIMIT 0, 10`. (when show 10 per page is selected). `SELECT * FROM user_pending_ads WHERE User_Name='staff1' LIMIT 5, 10` (the 5 changes per subsequent pages. Hence, `LIMIT 0, 10` is on the first page, `LIMIT 5,10` is on the second page etc.)

Comment: I don't know if there's hope on getting a fix for the pagination. I mix it with my search box so that only 1 result is displayed rather than having 2 of the same result displayed at once.